# How to count and sum in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table T1

```
ID     Type        Amount
1      1           100
2      2           100
3      2           100
4      2           100
5      1           100
6      1           100
7      2           100
8      1           100
9      1           100
```

I need result as follows

```
TotalRecods  Type1Recods type2Recods  Type1Amount type2Amount
9            5           4            500         400
```

I am trying

```
SELECT     COUNT(id) AS TotalRecords , 
           COUNT(type) AS Type1Records, 
           COUNT(type) AS Type2Records, 
           SUM(Amount ) AS Type1Amount, 
           SUM(Amount) AS Type2Amount 
 FROM         T1
```

its returning

```
TotalRecords Type1Records Type2Records Type1Amount Type2Amount
9            9            9            900         900
```

I dont understand how to filter it on type. may be a simple step I am missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT
        COUNT(*) [TotalRecords],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN 1 END) [Type1Records],
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN 1 END) [Type2Records],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN [Amount] END) [Type1Amount],
        SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 2 THEN [Amount] END) [Type2Amount]
    FROM
        [t];
```

Just note that if there is no record for some type, `COUNT` will return `0`, but result from `SUM` will `NULL`. If you want `0`  result also from `SUM` function, you can use it like:

`SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 1 THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END) [Type1Amount]`

Comment: sum( case when Type = 1 then Amount )  END is missing

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using `CASE` expressions.

**Query**

```
select count(*) as [TotalRecods],
sum(case when [Type] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Type1Recods],
sum(case when [Type] = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [Type2Recods],
sum(case when [Type] = 1 then Amount end) as [Type1Amount],
sum(case when [Type] = 2 then Amount end) as [Type2Amount],
from your_table_name;
```

Comment: right but late, SUM and COUNT are interchangeable with this syntax

Comment: @Jodrell : Yeah, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT     COUNT(id) AS TotalRecods , 
               (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM T1 WHERE type = 1) AS Type1Recods, 
               (SELECT COUNT(type) FROM T1 WHERE type = 2) AS Type2Recods, 
               (SELECT SUM(Amount ) FROM T1 WHERE type = 1) AS Type1Amount, 
               (SELECT SUM(Amount ) FROM T1 WHERE type = 2) AS Type2Amount 
     FROM   T1
```